Copy data from one widget to another page
I have an old flutter app that I want to show on the profile page of the user the reviews but when I add to the code it appears data with a red line saying name doesn't exist
    class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
      late ScrollController scrollController;
    
      UserPage({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<UserPage> createState() => UserProfile();
    }
    
    class UserProfile extends State<UserPage> {
      bool isFileImage = false;
      late User user;
      late File pickedFile;
      String? userImage;
      String? address;
      String? precise_address;
      String? userName;
      String? facebookUrl;
      String? instagramUrl;
      String? tikTokUrl;
    
      TextEditingController facebookController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController instagramController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController tiktokController = TextEditingController();
      late String userId;
      Random randomGenerator = Random();
    
      String? searchString;
      String? country;
    
      QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot;
      Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map>>? stream;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initUser();
      }
      final Algolia _algoliaApp = AlgoliaApplication.algolia;
    
      String? serviveProvideId;
      Future<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>> _operation(String input) async {
        AlgoliaQuery query = _algoliaApp.instance.index("users").search(input);
        AlgoliaQuerySnapshot querySnap = await query.getObjects();
        List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> results = querySnap.hits;
        return results;
      }
    
    
      initUser() async {
        user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
        userId = user.uid;
        logger.e("user id at init user =$userId");
        getSocialData();
        getData();
      }
    
      final TextEditingController _userNameController = TextEditingController();
    
      late File _image;
      final picker = ImagePicker();
    
      Future getImage() async {
        final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        if (pickedFile != null) {
          setState(() {
            _image = File(pickedFile.path);
          });
          Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
          Uint8List imageData = _image.readAsBytesSync();
          storageReference
              .child("Users Profile")
              .child(userId)
              .putData(imageData)
              .then((uploadTask) async {
            var dowurl = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
            String url = dowurl.toString();
    
            Map<String, dynamic> urlNull = {
              'avatarUrl': url,
            };
            DocumentReference prereference =
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId);
    
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
              transaction.update(prereference, urlNull);
            });
          });
        }
      }
Future<void> displayPrediction(Prediction p, BuildContext context) async {
    var placeId = p.placeId;
    var address = await FlGeocoder(Constants.googlePlaceKey)
        .findAddressesFromPlaceId(placeId!);
    setState(() {
      searchString = p.description!;
    });
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId).update({
      "precise_location": searchString,
    });
    country = address.first.country!.longName;
  }

  var addresses;
  var first;
  double lat = 0.0;
  double long = 0.0;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void viewReview(var ratings, String name, String review, String avatarUrl) {
      showGeneralDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        transitionDuration: const Duration(
          milliseconds: 400,
        ), // how long it takes to popup dialog after button click
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
          // your widget implementation
          return Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: SafeArea(
                // top: false,
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12, bottom: 0),
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                    spreadRadius: 1)
                              ],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundImage: const AssetImage(
                                        'assets/images/profilepic.png'),
                                    child: Image.network(avatarUrl),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                                  Text(name,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 50),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      _buildRatingStars(ratings),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
  Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 140,
                                child: Text(
                                  review,
                                  textScaleFactor: 1.1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Close',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return ListView(
        controller: widget.scrollController,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.32,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.09,
                 Positioned(
                  right: 24,
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                        child: Row(children: [
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map>>(
                                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection('Users')
                                      .doc(data['id'])
                                      .collection('BusinessAccount')
                                      .doc('detail')
                                      .collection('reviews')
                                      .snapshots(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                    }
                                    final data = snapshot.data?.docs;
                                    double average = 0;
                                    num sum = 0;
                                    for (var star in data!) {
                                      sum = sum + star['rating'];
                                    }
                                    average = sum / data.length;
                                    return Row(
                                      children: [
                                        data.isNotEmpty
                                            ? Text(
                                                average.toString(),
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.blue),
                                              )
                                            : const Text(
                                                'No Reviews',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.blue),
                                              ),
                                        data.isNotEmpty
                                            ? _buildRatingStars(1)
                                            : const SizedBox(),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  }),

and here at doc(data['id']) I get a red line under data , what I should add in the beginning , I don't know how to retrieve the data

Read firestore documentation. To get data from document snapshot use snaphot.data() function to get data in form of map.
